# Border in Chrome not visible

Tags: html, css

Implemented div in the project with the following CSS.

```css
div{

    border: 0.5px solid rgba(35, 199, 255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>     
  Menu
</div>
```

In Firefox and Internet Explorer the border of the `<div>` coming proper but in Chrome Browser border are not visible.

- Why It is happening ? Is it because of rgba values OR because of border width ?
- What is the solution ?
- When I replace 0.5px with 1px It is working fine in Chrome also.

Comment: No, it’s because of the border-width of `0.5px`. Use a full pixel.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks but Is Chrome not supports pixels in points.

Comment: Try to use box shadow to mimic border: http://jsfiddle.net/e843tjtz/

Comment: @dfsq : Yes, this works for me. Thanks a lot, Only thing is for more than 0.5 px say 3.5 px shadow will not look like border, in case of 0.5px this works

Comment: @VaibhavJain It should work with any size really: see http://jsfiddle.net/x5ook88d/1/ (I also updated my original answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, all CSS pixel values get truncated, so decimals won't work.
This means that in Chrome, `0.5px` will get truncated to `0px`.

The desired effect can however be accomplished using CSS's `box-shadow`

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/x5ook88d/1/

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3.5px rgba(35, 199, 255, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3.5px rgba(35, 199, 255, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3.5px rgba(35, 199, 255, 0.5);
```

Comment: True that Chrome doesn't support it. What about solution?

Comment: @dfsq: Yes, If Chrome doesn't support it. What is the solution to implement 0.5px radius in Chrome.

Comment: @VaibhavJain I would try to use box shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use full pixels check this example

```
div{
    border: 1px solid rgba(35, 199, 255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The only difference that i used 1px not 0.5px

```
<div>Menu</div>
```

Comment: But the problem is that OP needs 0.5 width, this is important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome truncated 0.5px border to 0px.

**But now it has been already fixed.**
Currently, rendered 0.5px border to 1px.
(Same as Internet Explorer and Firefox)

[229428 - Borders/outlines rounded down, other browsers round up - chromium - Monorail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229428)